# how do I get UIScrollView to open at a specific point?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

By default it just displays the very left side of the view, letting you scroll right. How can set it so that the first thing you see is, for example, the middle of the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this sort of code into your viewWillAppear method

```
scrollview.contentOffset = CGPointMake(<#xOffset#>, <#yOffset#>);
```